# Application Error while uploading to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

For my application's backend I'm trying to host in on heroku. After creating a new app on heroku I've followed all the steps that it showed me and it was deployed successfully. But when I go to the link it gives me application error. I tried to get the log by `heroku logs --tail` and it gave me this

```
2021-12-29T07:57:12.741895+00:00 app[web.1]: Error:  The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
2021-12-29T07:57:12.751654+00:00 app[web.1]: [nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
2021-12-29T07:58:11.201323+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2021-12-29T07:58:11.236815+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2021-12-29T07:58:11.259774+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2021-12-29T07:58:11.400798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22
2021-12-29T07:58:11.473743+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-29T08:56:18.088383+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pin-map-app.herokuapp.com request_id=30848095-cca3-4afe-b1ac-705529a0b023 fwd="103.166.88.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-29T08:56:19.043794+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=pin-map-app.herokuapp.com request_id=dedb7d05-a475-4e11-972d-e484b397c88e fwd="103.166.88.18" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

As you can see there's something with the `openUri()` problem and for this I had already set up `dotenv` and added `dotenv.config()` in my `index.js`. I tried `heroku restart` and pushed all the codes again but the problem remains same.
**index.js**

```
import express from "express";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import pinRoutes from "./routes/pins.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/users.js";
import cors from "cors";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors());
app.use("/pins", pinRoutes);
app.use("/user", userRoutes);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("welcome to pin it");
});

mongoose
  .connect(process.env.CONNECTION_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Error: ", err.message);
  });
```

In my `.env` file I only have the `CONNECTION_URL` and nothing else. I had deployed some other apps before but this is the first time I'm getting this type of error.

Comment: is your .env file in your root folder?
have you checked your procfile?

Comment: @Pandamora yes the env file is in the root folder and in Procfile I've added `web: npm run start` which is also in the root folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Firstly:** make sure that all the independence is installed in `package.json`

**Secondly:**

**Despite** your setup the correct environment, that shows you the `mongoose` error tell that something is **wrong** in your first parameter, try to make direct linking, **without** `.env`

just make sure that's the port which connected in it is:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

this just makes the port that connected dynamic
If port 3000 does not work will switch to another one.
```

#### And listen it as:

```
app.listen(port)
```

Comment: Removing the env file and putting the connection link directly did the work for me. but I don't understand why this happened.

Comment: There is one reason, The URL is not linked. that's mean your .env file does not work